# "returns" or "is returning", which one of the followings is true?

Tags: grammar

The question is, "Fay ------ from her holiday tomorrow evening." Fill the blank with "is returning" or "returns".

Which one would be true if used?

Comment: Both are acceptable. "Returns" strikes me as a bit formal. In casual conversation I'd be more likely to say "Faye gets back tomorrow" instead. (but use of "holiday" instead of "vacation" might mean you want a British answer rather than American)

Comment: Either would be correct. There is no difference in meaning or grammaticality. Which construction to choose is up to the speaker.

Comment: Well, I respect and thank you for these comments but this question was asked in my English exam today, I think our teacher thinks a bit different.

Comment: "Fay is returning from her holiday tomorrow evening" would suggest to me that you (the speaker) know she is, or may be, or is supposed to be, on her way already and will arrive home tomorrow evening.  "Fay returns from her holiday..." would suggest to me that she is supposed to get home tomorrow evening, and is scheduled to do so, but you're not 100% sure that she will.  Both sentences are grammatical and correct.

Comment: @tautophile actually by using the present simple form, the speaker is expressing the highest degree of certainty as to the event taking place

Comment: Choose the present continuous/progressive form, your teacher is probably testing expressions that are used to convey a prearranged/planned event in the future and it's very likely that he or she has *not* taught, or explained that the present simple is also used to express the future. But if they have, which is commendable, then tell your teacher that both answers are correct and give your reasons.